# Como colocar uma div no meio de dois elementos dentro de outra div?

Tags: html, css

Galera,

Como faço para colocar um texto de uma div no meio de uma outra div que possui duas fotos separadas.

```
<div>
<img>
<img>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
<div>
```

**Em amarelo e verde são as divs**

[image: Foto 1]

**Preciso que fique igual a esta imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: nao posso alterar a ordem do html, colocando o texto antes, ou dentro da div junto com as fotos.

Tentei mover a foto 2 com margim top até embaixo, e depois subir o texto com margin top negativo, mas ficou tudo fora do lugar, porque as imagens e o texto são enormes.

Comment: não pode alterar a ordem mas precisa colocar em outro lugar? difícil assim, só imagino colocando `position: absolute` na `div` com o texto e posicionando usando `margin-top`, mesmo assim não vai ficar tudo bonito, vai precisar colocar `margin` na segunda `div`, melhor seria colocar tudo na posição certa e evitar esse "ajustes"

Comment: Qual a necessidade de manter a ordem desse jeito? Siga o padrão de desenvolvimento, o único problema que vejo é a lógica que está seguindo.

Comment: Calma galera, as vezes é um html gerado dinamicamente que ele não tem acesso, só consegue mexer no css, ou algum template de wordpress e essas coisas. Mas pode ser que de para fazer sim só no CSS...

Comment: E o Box cinza é o que? Essas divs estão dentro de uma Section ou alguma outra div pai?

Comment: Então, eu estou no meu trabalho agora e estou editanto esta página https://www.superestagios.com.br/index/cadastroEmpresa.php
Preciso concertar a parte RESPONSIVA, eu dividi a foto da esquerda em duas partes e preciso colocar o questionário entre as duas, se não o questionário vai ficar lá embaixo, e nao pode. 
Dá um inspecionar aí na página, e olha a parte responsiva

Comment: Eu não posso alterar a ordem pq a página quando nao está resposiva, estao um ao lado do outro, então os elementos precisavam estar separados...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara vou te dar um um exemplo, mas qual é a chance dele dar certo no seu projeto..... quase nenhum, pois tem muita coisa ai que pode bugar o layout, até por causa dos `positions:absolut`

Repare que primeiro o `pai` precisa de `position:relative`, depois o div das imagens precisa de `position:absolut` e o texto também. Repare que a segunda imagem tem um `margin-top` referente a altura do texto que vc vai ter que colocar na mão em px, não tem como ser dinâmico essa altura, mas talvez nem precise pelo que vi no site. Agora o texto que tem um `margin-top` de 500px, referente a altura da primeira imagem que tb tem 500px de altura. Tb precisei colocar `display:block` nas imagens para ficar uma embaixo da outra. Já viu que é uma gambiarra do car*lho né...

Veja o exemplo. tudo está no CSS, e a sua estrutura do HTML continua intacta.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pai {
    position: relative;
}
.texto {
    margin-top: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
.imgs{
    position: absolute;
}
.imgs img{
    display: block;
}
.mt {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">

    <div class="imgs">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/500/500" alt="">
        <img class="mt" src="http://unsplash.it/500/500" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="texto">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam amet architecto ipsam ducimus debitis minus eum quaerat ratione expedita nulla odit, accusamus magni nesciunt eligendi id dolore libero porro vero, laboriosam eius eveniet repellat? Voluptas explicabo dolor quod deserunt soluta debitis facilis tempora recusandae sunt voluptate quisquam dolorem suscipit accusantium ipsum placeat voluptates, quis, optio ab maiores dicta aperiam labore nemo doloremque similique! Recusandae doloremque, aut beatae quam maiores quia? Quis repellendus inventore facere corporis deserunt. Nobis ipsum a quisquam? Mollitia, autem. Sequi facilis recusandae quo sunt voluptates consectetur, obcaecati aliquid minima nemo, nihil iusto magnam assumenda nulla? Veniam, est?</p>
    <div>

</div>
```

Comment: é exatamente assim que quero, mas como o projeto aqui é bem grande, fazer funcionar desse jeito é tenso...
Pegar sites poluídos pra mexer é tenso demais kk

Irei tentar fazer isso, obrigado.

Comment: O código desse site tá completamente poluído, varias divs desnecessárias, entre outros... mas acontece né hehe

Comment: ée... nao deu haha
coloquei exatamente, mas bugou tudo kk
até o cabeçalho que é inserido por include de outra pagina, desconfigurou... com esses positions absolute, relative, etc...

aconteceu muitas coisas que nem dá pra escrever kkk, mas enfim, obrigadão. 
Que eu não seja despedido kkk

Comment: Cara mexem com esse tipo de template é phoda, ainda mais em PHP. Por isso eu particularmente não uso, eu gosto de ter controle das coisas entende. Eh já imaginava que ia bugar já tinha falado rss, mas vai que da certo né... Vc pode tentar também usando display:flex e colocar order nos elementos. Da uma estudada nisso, as fezes pode ser uma opção tb